# What value to pass Const char*

Tags: c++

I am absolute beginner for c++ running through some code and faced below code

```
bool SomeFunction (const char* x, char* y, int z)
{
   //some code
}
```

now i want to pass value to the arguments for the above method

how to pass value to const char* X argument ?

and I am not understanding what is this ? is this pointer to char ?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what the specific *problem* is, but a general one is showing signs of rearing up. You can pass *any* pointer to `char` data; `const` or otherwise. The `const` *here* is simply a contract that this function claims it will honor; that it will not modify the data pointed to by `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`const char*` is indeed a point to a `char`. However, since strings are no more than a `char` array with a `\0` at the end, this is usually used to pass strings:

```
SomeFunction ("hello", "world", 12);
```